# React state for forms

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component with a form element, and I'm rendering multiple child components, each with a different set of radio button option to choose from. How do I get the selected option for each child passed back up to the parent for the form submission? I have the selected option set as the state for each child, but I don't understand how to get the parent to collect each one to store the option that a user selected.

Parent

```
const GameSelect = () => {
  const userNameRef = useRef();
  const [games, setGames] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchGames = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://nfl-schedule.p.rapidapi.com/v1/schedules",
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "nfl-schedule.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key":
              "35cba34c56msh4bdc15a4ca34516p11f9f6jsnb3c53161c895",
          },
        }
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Cannot retrieve games");
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      const games = data.data;
      const currentGames = [];
      const days = [
        "Sunday",
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday",
        "Saturday",
      ];

      for (const game in games) {
        currentGames.push({
          key: games[game].shortName,
          id: games[game].shortName,
          name: games[game].name,
          visitor: games[game].awayTeam.name,
          host: games[game].homeTeam.name,
          homeScore: games[game].homeTeam.score,
          awayScore: games[game].awayTeam.score,
          date:
            days[new Date(games[game].date).getDay()] +
            " " +
            new Date(games[game].date).toLocaleDateString() +
            " " +
            new Date(games[game].date).toLocaleTimeString([], {
              timeStyle: "short",
            }),
        });
      }
      setGames(currentGames);
    };

    fetchGames().catch(err => {
      setError(err.message);
    });
  }, []);

  const gameList = games.map(game => (
    <Game
      key={game.shortName}
      host={game.host}
      visitor={game.visitor}
      name={game.name}
      date={game.date}
    />
  ));

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const userName = userNameRef.current.value;

    fetch("https://office-pool-bc15f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/games.json", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        user: userName,
        games: games,
      }),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="games">
      <h1>Week 1 Games</h1>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <input type="text" id="name" required ref={userNameRef} />
        <ul>{gameList}</ul>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Child

```
const Game = props => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

  const selectHandler = e => {
    setSelected(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <li>
      <h2>{props.name}</h2>
      <h5>{props.date}</h5>
      <div onChange={selectHandler}>
        <input
          id={props.visitor}
          className="radio hide"
          type="radio"
          name={props.name}
          value={props.visitor}
          required
        />
        <label htmlFor={props.visitor} className="label">
          {props.visitor}
        </label>
      </div>
      <br></br>
      <div onChange={selectHandler}>
        <input
          id={props.host}
          value={props.host}
          className="radio hide"
          type="radio"
          name={props.name}
        />
        <label htmlFor={props.host} className="label">
          {props.host}
        </label>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};
```

Comment: Bring the states up to the parent element and pass them down as prop to each child.

Comment: Without a specific example this is all very generic.  But *in general* if the state is managed in the parent component then that component would pass its state and a function to update its state to the child component.  The child component wouldn't try to internally manage that same state, but would just use the value/function given to it.

Comment: I'm making a football pickem app. So I'm fetching all the games scheduled for each week, and each child component is an individual game. Once an option for each game is selected, the parent submits the form and I want to POST which choice was made for each one. I know how to lift state up (or at least I think I do) but all I can manage is the parent state becomes the most recent child state change.